# How to send signals to consumer in django?

Tags: django, websocket, signals

I'm developing WebSocket programs in Django. I want to receive the request from the client(ReactJS) and send signals to WebSocket consumer, and then WebSocket consumer sends messages to the client.
How to solve such a problem?

I tried as following.

- urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [  
    url(r'^updatesignal/$',updatesignal),  
    url(r'^stopsignal/$',stopsignal),  
]
```

- views.py

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def updatesignal(request):
    print("update")
    consumers.isconnected = 1

    return Response("update signal")

@api_view(['POST'])
def stopsignal(request):
    print("stop signal")
    consumers.isconnected = 0

    return Response("stop signal")
```

- consumers.py

```py
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json
import asyncio

isconnected = 0
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        print("connect")
        await self.accept()
        while isconnected == 1:
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
            print("true")
            # obj = # do_something (Ex: constantly query DB...)

            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'message': "aaa"
            }))

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        # Receive message from WebSocket
        .....
```

But WebSocket consumer is fired after 10 seconds after receiving update signal request. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry for the wrong format. Thank you for your editing.